# Run script at login screen

Tags: command-line, bash, login

I wrote a script which is supposed to run at the login screen (It reads the serial stream of an arduino and types my password into the password box .. ). How can I run this script after boot but before the login?

Comment: Can you share the script?

Answer (score 2):

You can configure lightdm to call your script in `/etc/init/lightdm.conf` in such a way that it gets executed after starting lightdm. Just open the .conf file, and call your script under the section `post-stop script`.